# Построение Get запроса с использованием Retrofit android

Tags: android, клиент-сервер, retrofit

В моем приложении на андроид необходимо отправлять get запросы при помощи retrofit, данный запрос должен иметь я так думаю определенные параметры, мне их сбросили бекендщики:

```
HTTP 200
{
    "count": int, # number of messages 
    "messages": [ # array of messages
        {
            "id": int, # message id
            "subject": str, # message subject
            "can_delete": int, # can it be deleted (1) or not (0)
            "new": int # message already read (0) or not (1)
            "date": str, # date of message in 'd.m.y'. If message was sent today format will be 'H:M'
            "receiver_name": str, # name of receiver if type=1
            "sender_name": str, # name of sender if type=0
        }, ...
    ],
    "next_url": URL,  # url for get next messages, if no more messages value is null
    "previous_url": URL # url for get previous messages, if no more messages value is null
}
```

и вот у меня возник вопрос - в двойных скобках у нас указаны параметры и дальше написаны их единицы измерения, и я не могу понять как построить запрос с приведенными параметрами, и дальше как этот интерфейс проинициализировать. У меня есть интерфейс для построения всех запросов из приложения:

```
Call<List<IncomeMessages>> getInMess(@Query("count") Integer method);
```

если я правильно понял (как было написано в моих источниках) нужно использовать query для того что-бы прописать все переменные. Вот в удачном ответе есть определенное разветвление, например messages состоит из отдельных класификаторов, и мне нужно создавать новый get запрос только для этого поля, или можно все переменные, count, messages, next/previous url , разместить в пределах одного запроса. Что мне еще не совсем понятно как мне потом различать полученные данные после получения их с сервера. Буду очень благодарен за помощь в решении данного запроса, так как сижу уже все выходные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вы поделились не всей информацией, которую вам предоставили разработчики бэкенда, но глядя на то, что вы показали, я бы сказал, что в указанном коде приведен пример успешного ответа сервера на какой-то запрос, причем данные возвращаются в формате json.
Для того, чтобы корректно обработать весь полученный ответ необходимо создать класс, в котором будут описаны все поля этого ответа (т.н. POJO-класс) и именно объект этого класса нужно просить вернуть Retrofit.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Message {
    @SerializedName("id")
    int id;
    @SerializedName("subject")
    String subject;
    @SerializedName("can_delete")
    int isCanDelete;
    @SerializedName("new")
    int isNew;
    @SerializedName("date")
    String date;
    @SerializedName("receiver_name")
    String receiverName;
    @SerializedName("sender_name")
    String senderName;
}

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

public class MessageAnswer {
    @SerializedName("count")
    int count;
    @SerializedName("messages")
    List<Message> messages;
    @SerializedName("next_url")
    URL nextUrl;
    @SerializedName("previous_url")
    URL previousUrl;
}
```

А сам интерфейс Retrofit тогда может выглядеть так:

```
@Headers("Content-type: application/json")
@GET("/list?type=0")
Call<MessageAnswer> getInMess(@Query("count") Integer method);
```

Comment: на данный момент это почти вся информация, остальное - это ответы в случае неудачного ответа. Я думаю что эти ответы вам ничем не помогут)) насколько я понял с вашего ответа, вы утверждаете что нужно создать два классы - за запрос и за ответ. Так как сейчас я использую один класс для отправки запроса.

Comment: Не совсем. В своем ответе я рекомендую сделать класс для объекта внутри массива (класс объекта сообщения {
            "id": int, # message id
            "subject": str, # message subject
            ....) и класс самого ответа, то что хранит сам список сообщений, количество, следующий url, предыдущий url. И от retrofit требовать распарсить именно класс ответа, в котором уже будет список сообщений. Просто ещё и не до конца понятен ваш вопрос, с чем именно трудность у вас?

Comment: у меня трудность с прописыванием параметров в interface и дальнейшая инициализация данного интерфейса в главном классе. я не могу понять что и куда писать.)

Comment: В вашем примере спецификаций не указаны параметры запроса. В этом примере кода указан только пример ответа сервера.

Comment: что такое спецификация запроса? что-то типа post/get?

Comment: Не только. Должно быть описано какие параметры можно отправить на сервер, под какими именами. Есть ещё не самая плохая статья по использованию ретрофита, если вы не знаете как им пользоваться: https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/506-retrofit.html

Comment: я эту статью уже несколько раз перечитал и все равно не нашел решения моих проблем, я так понял что я отправляю GET запрос на сервер с указанными параметрами(атрибуты входящего сообщения) вот я еще нашел пример запроса: curl -i -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization:Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" https://сервер/v1/message/list?type=TYPE

Comment: а вот у меня еще вопрос возник, в вашем ответе вы указывали в каждом классе по три точки, я так понял что туда нужно еще что-то дописать, а что именно нужно туда написать, ну то есть я так понял что один класс мы делаем запрос и получаем все поля с сервера которые только можно, а класс-ответ я так понял выводит только то что нужно?

Comment: Обновил пример для лучшего понимания смысла классов. Если ещё не понятно, то попробуйте самостоятельно почитать про POJO-классы. Эти классы нужны для того, чтобы преобразовать json в java-объект.

Comment: мне честно говоря, вроде все понятно, но чем вы руководствовались когда создавали эти два класса и интерфейс, а именно как вы поняли какие поля в какой класс писать. И почему в интерфейсе только одно поле, я думал что нужно писать все поля какие нам нужны

Comment: Вы вообще знаете что такое json и какова его структура? Потому что в вашем json-ответе от сервера приходит массив объектов с полями id, subject, can_delete, new, date, receiver_name, sender_name. Для того, чтобы retrofit при помощи Gson смог нормально преобразовать массив этих объектов вам и нужен отдельный класс. Ну и для того, чтобы Gson смог понять где искать этот массив вам нужен второй класс. Почитайте внимательно про Json и Gson, посмотрите примеры.

Comment: ок я понял, стратегию развития, но у мне как-бы не сильно понятно, как инициализировать этот интерфейс в главном классе, просто когда я прописываю  mAPIService.getInMess(a).enqueue(new Callback<MessageAnswer>() то переменной a нужно присвоить какое-то значение, так вот нужно ли это делать, или есть какой-то другой способ?

Comment: В вашем интерфейсе указано, что у вас есть параметр вашего get запроса: @Query("count") Integer method, именно поэтому вам и нужно передавать переменную при вызове метода getInMess(1). Я просто не знаю, что это за параметр, видимо это количество получаемых сообщений.

Comment: да это количество сообщений но, это не сильно помогло, все равно ошибка