# Interafce GET запрос retrofit android

Tags: android, get, клиент-сервер, retrofit

Я уже много задал вопросов по разработке приложения с использованием retrofit библиотеки и после всех ответов понял что нужно изначально структурировать задание и понять что делать, а после задавать вопросы. Так вот мне нужно получить с сервера список входящих сообщений и потом уже с ними работать. В моих предыдущих вопросах: [Как послать get запрос retrofit android?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/859454/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-get-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-retrofit-android) вы можете увидеть информацию которую мне предоставили разработчики серверной части приложения. И у меня возник вопрос нужно ли создавать кучу get запросов для получения всех параметров сообщения или же нужно создать один запрос в который уместить все параметры. Второй вопрос - обязательно ли создавать класс-запрос и класс-ответ для реализации данной задачи, или можно обойтись только классом-запросом. У меня есть уже запрос post который я реализовал при помощи только интерфейса и класса-запроса, мне почему-то казалось что эти два вида запросов одинаковые но оказалось что это не так. Заранее спасибо за любую помощь и полезные советы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кучу get-запросов на одно сообщение, а их ещё и список - самому не кажется ли бредом? Одним запросом получаете всё (вернее порцию сообщений, судя по инфе бэкэнда).

Если Вам не нужно передавать на сервер данные в теле запроса - то класс, описывающий это тело, естественно, не нужен.
А вот класс ответа указывать обязательно.
Создавать класс для ответа:

- нужно когда Вы хотите получить данные из ответа в виде java-объекта - Вы должны описать его класс и указать этот класс в api-интерфейсе.
- не нужно когда Вам нужен "сырой" ответ (строка, массив байт) - указываете стандартный класс `ResponseBody`
- не нужно когда ответ **можно и нужно** сконвертировать в какой-то другой существующий класс (список строк, к примеру - `List<String>`) - его и указываем в интерфейсе

Comment: то есть нужно создавать один запрос с параметром @Query, а вот дальше про конвертацию в другой класс из последнего пункта вашего списка не очень понятно, это мне нужно прописать там все поля которые будут в этом списке?

Comment: Это если формат ответа подходит для конвертации в этот класс. Для `List<String>`, например - это может быть json вида: `["текст","ещё_текст","снова_текст", "всё_время_текст"]`

Comment: ну да я получаю с сервера json a дальше мне его нужно рассовать по списку. С вашего ответа я могу сделать вывод что мне не нужен класс-запрос, а нужен класс ответ, где будет прописаны все поля которые я получу с сервера в json.

Comment: Именно так - точнее Вам нужно два класса для ответа, как Вам уже предложили: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/859246/11515. Только метод апи-интерфейса нужно довести до ума, согласно доке бэкэнда (добавить хедер авторизации, исправить путь и query.

Comment: спасибо буду ковыряться дальше, если что буду задавать вопросы более точно.