# Классы для GET запроса retrofit android дальнейшая инициализация

Tags: android, get, клиент-сервер, retrofit

У меня в приложении нужно послать запрос для получения списка входящих сообщений при помощи retrofit android. Вот я создал такие классы:
1. Класс-запрос - я так понял что этот класс будет запрашивать все данные с сервера которые нам нужны для дальнейшей работы. Вот код:

```
public class NewMessRequest {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("subject")
    @Expose
    private String subject;
    @SerializedName("can_delete")
    @Expose
    private String canDelete;
    @SerializedName("new")
    @Expose
    private String _new;
    @SerializedName("date")
    @Expose
    private String date;
    @SerializedName("receiver_name")
    @Expose
    private String receiverName;
    @SerializedName("sender_name")
    @Expose
    private String senderName;
    @SerializedName("count")
    @Expose
    private String count;
    @SerializedName("messages")
    @Expose
    private NewMessAnswer messages;
    @SerializedName("next_url")
    @Expose
    private String nextUrl;
    @SerializedName("previous_url")
    @Expose
    private String previousUrl;

    public NewMessRequest(String id, String subject, String canDelete, String _new, String date, String receiverName, String senderName, String count, NewMessAnswer messages, String nextUrl, String previousUrl) {
        this.id = id;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.canDelete = canDelete;
        this._new = _new;
        this.date = date;
        this.receiverName = receiverName;
        this.senderName = senderName;
        this.count = count;
        this.messages = messages;
        this.nextUrl = nextUrl;
        this.previousUrl = previousUrl;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getCanDelete() {
        return canDelete;
    }

    public void setCanDelete(String canDelete) {
        this.canDelete = canDelete;
    }

    public String get_new() {
        return _new;
    }

    public void set_new(String _new) {
        this._new = _new;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getReceiverName() {
        return receiverName;
    }

    public void setReceiverName(String receiverName) {
        this.receiverName = receiverName;
    }

    public String getSenderName() {
        return senderName;
    }

    public void setSenderName(String senderName) {
        this.senderName = senderName;
    }

    public String getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(String count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public NewMessAnswer getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(NewMessAnswer messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public String getNextUrl() {
        return nextUrl;
    }

    public void setNextUrl(String nextUrl) {
        this.nextUrl = nextUrl;
    }

    public String getPreviousUrl() {
        return previousUrl;
    }

    public void setPreviousUrl(String previousUrl) {
        this.previousUrl = previousUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "NewMessRequest{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", subject='" + subject + '\'' +
                ", canDelete='" + canDelete + '\'' +
                ", _new='" + _new + '\'' +
                ", date='" + date + '\'' +
                ", receiverName='" + receiverName + '\'' +
                ", senderName='" + senderName + '\'' +
                ", count='" + count + '\'' +
                ", messages=" + messages +
                ", nextUrl='" + nextUrl + '\'' +
                ", previousUrl='" + previousUrl + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

2.Класс-ответ - этот класс будет выбирать из класса-запроса отдельные параметры (я так понял). Вот код:

```
public class NewMessAnswer {
        int count;
        @SerializedName("messages_list")
        private ArrayList<NewMessRequest> messages;

        public NewMessAnswer(ArrayList<NewMessRequest> messages) {
            this.messages = messages;
        }

        public ArrayList<NewMessRequest> getMessages() {
            return messages;
        }

        public void setMessages(ArrayList<NewMessRequest> messages) {
            this.messages = messages;
        }
    }
```

3.Интерфейс для работы с эти  запросом:

```
@Headers({
            "Content-type: application/json",
            "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"})
    @GET("/v1/message/list?type=TYPE")
    Call<List<NewMessAnswer>> getInMess(@Query("id") Integer id,
                    @Query("subject") String subject,
                    @Query("can_delete") Integer can_delete,
                    @Query("new") Integer new_m,
                    @Query("date") String date,
                    @Query("receiver_name") String receiver_name,
                    @Query("sender_name") String sender_name,
                    @Query("next_url") URL next_url,
                    @Query("previous_url") URL previous_url);
```

4.Инициализация всех вышеприведенных элементов пока-что хромает, поэтому я привожу только стартовый вариант:

```
public void info() {
        Integer a,b,c;
        String r,s,g,e;

            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://0/")
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

            //Call<List<NewMessAnswer>> listCall = mAPIService.getInMess(a,b,c,);

        }
```

У меня возникло несколько вопросов:

1. Для нормального выполнения запроса необходимо создать два класса - запрос и ответ. Если за класс-запрос у меня есть уверенность что он вроде правильный, то за класс ответ я не уверен что я его правильно написал.
2. Второй вопрос это инициализация всего этого комплекса в главном классе. Честно сказать я вообще не могу понять как инициализировать это все. При инициализации у меня на данный момент студия просит ввести все переменные которые есть рядом с функцией @Query. То есть нужно все их прописать и предварительно инициализировать, присвоить им какие-то значения или что-то типа того. Мне эта часть разработки данного запроса вообще не понятна. 
   Если кто раньше видел то я уже задавал подобные вопросы, и получил хорошие ответы, которые я использовал для дальнейшей разработки. Но у меня все-же остались кое-какие вопросы. Буду благодарен за помощь и ценные советы. В случае неполного раскрытия вопроса могу дополнить его всеми нужными материалами.

Мои предыдущие вопросы:
[Interafce GET запрос retrofit android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/859539/interafce-get-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-retrofit-android)

[Построение Get запроса с использованием Retrofit android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/859186/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-get-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-retrofit-android/859246#859246)

Comment: Снова-здорова - откуда опять Вам померещился класс-запрос? Оба класса - это ответ. Один класс - контейнер, который содержит список сообщений и немножко служебных данных. Второй - собственно само сообщение - элемент списка. На сервер это всё слать не нужно - он Вам присылает данные в заведомо предопределённом формате и не требует указывать его содержание. Бэкэнд Вам написал, что Вы должны передать в `query` параметр `type` (обязательно) и параметр `offset` (необязательно) и всё.

Comment: спасибо за уточнение)) буду продолжать свои потуги))