# Получение списка android retrofit

Tags: android, listview

У меня в приложении нужно получить список входящих сообщений с сервера, для выполнения этой задачи я сделал такие действия:
создал интерфейс:

```
    Call<ListOfMess> getInMess(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Query("type") int type, @Query("offset") int offset);
```

создал класс-ответ в котором я определил поля которые я хочу вытащить из ответа:

```
       public class ResponseMessage {
    private int count;
    private List<MyMessage> messages;
    private String next_url;
    private String previous_url;

    public ResponseMessage() {
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public List<MyMessage> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(List<MyMessage> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public String getNext_url() {
        return next_url;
    }

    public void setNext_url(String next_url) {
        this.next_url = next_url;
    }

    public String getPrevious_url() {
        return previous_url;
    }

    public void setPrevious_url(String previous_url) {
        this.previous_url = previous_url;
    }

}
```

и еще один класс:

```
public class MyMessage{
    private int id;
    private String subject;
    private boolean can_delete;
    @SerializedName("new") 
    private int newField;
    private String date;
    private String receiver_name;
    private String sender_name;

    public MyMessage(){}

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public boolean isCan_delete() {
        return can_delete;
    }

    public void setCan_delete(boolean can_delete) {
        this.can_delete = can_delete;
    }

    public int getNewField() {
        return newField;
    }

    public void setNewField(int newField) {
        this.newField = newField;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getReceiver_name() {
        return receiver_name;
    }

    public void setReceiver_name(String receiver_name) {
        this.receiver_name = receiver_name;
    }

    public String getSender_name() {
        return sender_name;
    }

    public void setSender_name(String sender_name) {
        this.sender_name = sender_name;
    }
}
```

дальше я сделал класс адаптер для списка:

```
public class StateAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<State> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int layout;
    private List<State> states;

    public StateAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<State> states) {
        super(context, resource, states);
        this.states = states;
        this.layout = resource;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(this.layout, parent, false);

        ImageView icon = view.findViewById(R.id.mess);
        TextView subject = view.findViewById(R.id.subject);
        TextView from = view.findViewById(R.id.from);
        TextView to = view.findViewById(R.id.to);

        State state = states.get(position);


        icon.setImageResource(state.getIcon());
        subject.setText(state.getSubject());
        from.setText(state.getFrom());
        to.setText(state.getTo());


        return view;
    }
}
```

и еще один класс для списка:

```
public class State{
    private String subject;
    private String to;
    private String from;
    private int icon;

    public State(String subject, String to, String from, int icon) {
        this.subject = subject;
        this.to = to;
        this.from = from;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public int getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(int icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }
}
```

и дальше я хочу вытащенные данные из ответа запихнуть в этот список и что-бы он добавлял новые строки в списке самостоятельно динамически. Я использовал для работы этот [сайт](https://metanit.com/java/android/5.6.php). Но там записи уже были инициализированы, то есть их добавили вручную, а мне нужно что-бы список дополнялся самостоятельно, и я не знаю как это сделать. 
Я создал список в фрагменте с функцией которая содержит обращение к серверу, ниже кусок кода отвечающий за это:

```
 public void sent() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://сервер/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

        mAPIService.getInMess("Bearer " + access_token, 1, 1).enqueue(new Callback<ListOfMess>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ListOfMess> call, @NonNull Response<ListOfMess> response) {
                TextView sub = Objects.requireNonNull(getView()).findViewById(R.id.subject);
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String subject = response.body().getSubject();
                    //sub.setText(subject);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ListOfMess> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

я думаю может как-то инициализировать данный список в той части где `if(responce.isSuccerssful)`??
Если кто понял суть моего вопроса то буду очень признателен за полезные советы и информацию.

Comment: я вот тут прочитал только-что, что вроде как в recyclerView можно динамически добавлять элементы списка, может его использовать?)

Comment: Если вам нужно получить список объектов ListOfMess то нужно в интерфейсе писать  Call<List<ListOfMess>>

Comment: а чем оно отличается от просто call, все равно выводить я так понял будет одно и тоже

Comment: внутри <> пишеться тип объекта который приходит вам в ответ на запрос.

Comment: не очень понятно если честно, вот у меня был call просто и мне приходит в ответ все входящие или исходящие сообщения, а теперь что-то изменится если вставить list?

Comment: вот я сделал так как вы советуете то честно сказать разницы не вижу особой в пришедшем ответе))

Comment: Зачем у Вас два одинаковых класса (разница в названии и одном поле) - можно использовать один `State` и в запросе и в адаптере. Лишние поля Gson'у не помеха - он их просто не трогает.

Comment: ок я понял, но тем не менее я пока не смог распихать из пришедшего ответа строки в список, и даже в textview. возможно я что-то не учел.))

Comment: И я Вам уже писал по поводу разницы между `class` и `List<class>`. И не только я про то что скобках у `Call<здесь>` нужно указывать класс желаемого ответа. Как Вы можете "распихать" в целый список одно сообщение (судя по коду в вопросе). Разве это не тот же сервер: [Построение Get запроса с использованием Retrofit android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/859186/11515)?

Comment: а что разве такое нельзя реализовать?? ну вот мне приходят по одному запросу входящие а по второму исходящие сообщения, и это не одно сообщение а все что есть входящие, и я так думал что можно как-то вытащить из ответа данные и закинуть в список, если нельзя, то я честно сказать даже не представляю как это реализовать. Должно вообще выглядеть как в обычной почте, например как в приложении gmail и что-то подобное, да сервер тот-же

Comment: Посмотрите на Ваш класс `ListOfMess` - Вы видите в нём список сообщений? лично я вижу одно и близко не похожее на json в том вопросе. Вам нужно использовать классы, которые Вам дали в ответе и переписать адаптер - это пример для смсок, по-моему.

Comment: но мне вроде классов не давали в ответе, там есть только массив сообщений, вы его имеете в виду?

Comment: обновил вопрос с новыми классами, надеюсь в этот раз все верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@GET("/v1/message/list")
Call<ResponseMessage> getInMess(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Query("type") int type, @Query("offset") int offset);
```

---

```
@Override
public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResponseMessage> call, @NonNull Response<ResponseMessage> response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        List<MyMessage> messages = response.body().getMessages();
        // адаптер должен быть уже проинициализирован
        // и добавлен в LisView (или что там у Вас)
        adapter.addAll(messages);
        // говорим адаптеру, что данные изменились
        // и нужно перерисоваться
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else { ... }
}
```

---

```
public class StateAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyMessage> {

    public StateAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @NonNull
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // здесь рекомендуется использовать холдер
        // а не искать вьюшки каждый раз
        ImageView icon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.mess);
        TextView subject = convertView.findViewById(R.id.subject);
        TextView from = convertView.findViewById(R.id.from);
        TextView to = convertView.findViewById(R.id.to);

        MyMessage msg = getItem(position);

        // здесь я не знаю откуда и по какому условию
        // у Вас берётся картинка - додумайте сами и добавьте
        // метод getIcon() в MyMessage
        // icon.setImageResource(msg.getIcon());

        subject.setText(msg.getSubject());
        from.setText(msg.getSender_name());
        to.setText(msg.getReceiver_name());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за столь полный ответ, надеюсь заработает, завтра если будет все норм отпишусь за результат, но вы в любом случае узнаете о продвижении моих работ)))

Comment: а есть варианты почему не видит response.body().getMessages(); getMessages, хотя в ResponseMessage такая функция есть?

Comment: В параметрах метода `onResponse` `<ResponseMessage>` указан? И что написано в предупреждении?

Comment: да и там тоже указан

Comment: Может имя метода неправильно написано, попробуйте убрать, начать вводить, автодополнение покажет...

Comment: я так пробовал, автодополнение его не видит вообще, может давайте я вопрос обновлю с новыми данными?

Comment: Новый задавайте - не надо ломать логику

Comment: ок, сейчас создам))