# Как заполнить список RecyclerView элементами полученными с сервера android

Tags: android

У меня в приложении нужно получить списки входящих и исходящих приложений, которые хранятся на сервере. Ознакомившись с литературой и форумами я решил что лучшим вариантом для создания списка будет RecyclerView так как он лучше чем ListView по многим параметрам. Некоторые из этапов моих "стараний" есть в моем предыдущем вопросе: [Получение списка android retrofit](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/862850/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-android-retrofit). Спасибо @woesss за ответ. Мой нынешний вопрос будет содержать все мои последние наработки с учетом ответов StackOwerflow и моих собственных поисков. Итак, для начала я создал интерфейс:

```
@Headers({"Content-type: application/json"})
@GET("/v1/message/list")
Call<List<ResponseMessage>> getInMess(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Query("type") int type, @Query("offset") int offset);
```

дальше я создал два класса для обработки ответа полученного с сервера:

**а)**

```
public class MyMessage{
    private int id;
    private String subject;
    private boolean can_delete;
    @SerializedName("new")
    private int newField;
    private String date;
    private String receiver_name;
    private String sender_name;

    public MyMessage(){}

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public boolean isCan_delete() {
        return can_delete;
    }

    public void setCan_delete(boolean can_delete) {
        this.can_delete = can_delete;
    }

    public int getNewField() {
        return newField;
    }

    public void setNewField(int newField) {
        this.newField = newField;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getReceiver_name() {
        return receiver_name;
    }

    public void setReceiver_name(String receiver_name) {
        this.receiver_name = receiver_name;
    }

    public String getSender_name() {
        return sender_name;
    }

    public void setSender_name(String sender_name) {
        this.sender_name = sender_name;
    }
}
```

**b)**

```
public class ResponseMessage {
    private int count;
    private List<MyMessage> messages;
    private String next_url;
    private String previous_url;

    public ResponseMessage() {
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public List<MyMessage> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(List<MyMessage> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public String getNext_url() {
        return next_url;
    }

    public void setNext_url(String next_url) {
        this.next_url = next_url;
    }

    public String getPrevious_url() {
        return previous_url;
    }

    public void setPrevious_url(String previous_url) {
        this.previous_url = previous_url;
    }
}
```

и инициализация `retrofit` :

```
public void received() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://сервер/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();


        String access_token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhcGkuam9iLXNlcnZlci5uZXQiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjo5NTMzOTYxLCJleHAiOjE1MzgzMTE4NDB9.kFdYFGnhPGD_gVH3xG_uLpeJuMNYRgiakIVLm48KtMM";
        final APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        mAPIService.getInMess("Bearer " + access_token, 0, 1).enqueue(new Callback<List<ResponseMessage>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<ResponseMessage>> call, @NonNull Response<List<ResponseMessage>> response) {

            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<ResponseMessage>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

следующим шагом стало создание `recyclerView`:

**1)**

```
public class Message
{
    private String subject;
    private String to;
    private String from;
    //private int image;

    public Message(String subject, String to/*, String from,int image*/) {
        this.subject = subject;
        this.to = to;
        this.from = from;
        //this.image = image;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    /*public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }*/
}
```

**2)**

```
  class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<MyMessage> messages;

    DataAdapter(Received context, List<MyMessage> messageList) {
        this.messages = messageList;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context здесь почему-то ошибка с context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_of_rec_m, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyMessage message = messages.get(position);
        //holder.imageView.setImageResource(message.());
        holder.subjView.setText(message.getSubject());
        holder.fromView.setText(message.getSender_name());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final ImageView imageView;
        final TextView subjView, fromView;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            subjView = view.findViewById(R.id.subject);
            fromView = view.findViewById(R.id.from);
        }
    }
}
```

и теперь собственно сам вопрос: как можно увидеть с моего кода, у меня есть фрагмент на вкладке в котором есть RecyclerView для сообщений. У меня проблема)) Проблема состоит в том что я только недавно начал работать с фрагментами и плохо знаю как инициализировать там виджеты. Я смог сделать инициализацию элемента только в onViewCreated и тогда из других функций этот элемент не видится, либо пробовал сделать инициализацию сразу в функции но тогда не находит по id тот или иной элемент. То есть я не могу создать адаптер для списка кроме как в onViewCreated. Либо нужно как-то его сделать видимым по всему фрагменту либо сделать инициализацию только в нужной функции, либо передавать параметры входящих сообщений в адаптер, но я с трудом представляю как это сделать. Ну и самый насущный вопрос - как сделать нормально список с сообщениями. Вроде все классы есть но почему-то не работает так как нужно, а если до конца быть честным то вообще никак не работает))

### UPDATE

Я ознакомился с предложенным вопросом и создал свои классы для получения списка сообщений:
**1)**

```
public class Message {
    private int id;
    private String subject;
    private boolean can_delete;
    @SerializedName("new") //this is because new is a protected keyword. this annotation is for Gson parsing library. Any library has his own annotation
    private int newField;
    private String date;
    private String receiver_name;
    private String sender_name;

    public Message() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public boolean isCan_delete() {
        return can_delete;
    }

    public void setCan_delete(boolean can_delete) {
        this.can_delete = can_delete;
    }

    public int getNewField() {
        return newField;
    }

    public void setNewField(int newField) {
        this.newField = newField;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getReceiver_name() {
        return receiver_name;
    }

    public void setReceiver_name(String receiver_name) {
        this.receiver_name = receiver_name;
    }

    public String getSender_name() {
        return sender_name;
    }

    public void setSender_name(String sender_name) {
        this.sender_name = sender_name;
    }
}
```

**2)**

```
public class MessageArray {
    private int count;
    private List<Message> messages;
    private String next_url;
    private String previous_url;

    public MessageArray() {
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public List<Message> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(List<Message> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public String getNext_url() {
        return next_url;
    }

    public void setNext_url(String next_url) {
        this.next_url = next_url;
    }

    public String getPrevious_url() {
        return previous_url;
    }

    public void setPrevious_url(String previous_url) {
        this.previous_url = previous_url;
    }
}
```

**3) Класс-адаптер для списка:**

```
class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private List<Message> messageList;
    private Context ctx;

    public MessageAdapter(List<Message> messageList, Context ctx) {
        this.messageList = messageList;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_of_rec_m, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message message = messageList.get(position);
        holder.subject.setText(message.getSubject());
        holder.from.setText(message.getSender_name());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messageList.size();
    }


    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView from,subject;
        ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            subject = v.findViewById(R.id.subject);
            from = v.findViewById(R.id.from);

            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**4)** ошибка из-за которой у меня слетает приложение:

```
 --------- beginning of crash
08-03 02:05:42.340 1733-1733/com.example.developer_4.test_login E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.developer_4.test_login, PID: 1733
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.developer_4.test_login.Tabs.Received.onViewCreated(Received.java:51)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1471)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2623)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2410)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2365)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2242)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:654)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:168)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
        at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:95)
        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1536)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:803)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1121)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:689)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2275)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1366)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1619)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

**5)** строка в которой ошибка:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); - здесь эта ошибка
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        received();
    }

    public void received() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://сервер/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        adapter = null;
        //recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        tok_pref = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSharedPreferences(ACCESS_TOKEN,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        String access_token = tok_pref.getString(ACCESS_TOKEN,"");
        final APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        mAPIService.getInMess("Bearer " + access_token, 0, 1).enqueue(new Callback<MessageArray>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<MessageArray> call, @NonNull Response<MessageArray> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    messageArrayList = (ArrayList<Message>) response.body().getMessages();
                    adapter = new MessageAdapter(messageArrayList, getActivity());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<MessageArray> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Очень надеюсь что я не очень запутанно объяснил свою проблему, и мне здесь помогут добрым советом. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Теперь понятно почему нет метода... : `<List<ResponseMessage>>` - при чём тут `List`? Вам приходит один `ResponseMessage` со списком сообщений внутри , а не целый список этих `ResponseMessage`-ей.

Comment: то есть List убрать, если массив сообщений есть уже в ResponseMessage?

Comment: Да, убрать - тип должен соответствовать json из ответа - у Вас объект (`{...}`), а не массив (`[...]`).

Comment: там массив сообщений есть

Comment: Да массив сообщений, но не массив ответов сервера. И он **внутри** объекта и в классе этого объекта у Вас для него объявлен список - именно туда попадут сообщения. Программа не умеет думать за Вас - она выполняет инструкции - массив в объекте не тоже самое, что массив объектов

Comment: ок я теперь понял что вы имеете в виду, теперь нужно как-то из ответа вытащить данные и закинуть в список, а вот у меня еще вопрос возник, как лучше в моей ситуации, использовать отдельные фрагменты или целые активити для размещения там списка сообщений и вывода на экран?

Comment: У меня был отдельный класс (который хранит список экземпляров класса), вот в нем я и получал

Comment: я так понимаю что в тех классах что я привел в вопросе, такого класса нету? я планировал что это будет класс message

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ

Comment: как раз просматриваю, спасибо, если что уточню если будет что-то не понятно

Comment: Только на интерфейсы не смотрите, они к этому не относятся

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведу пример кода, который у меня есть.

Имеется модель:

```
public class Shop implements Serializable {

    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public String modeWork;
    public String url;
    public Double latitude;
    public Double longitude;
    public ChainStore chainStore;

    public Shop(int id, String name, String address, String modeWork, String url, Double latitude, Double longitude, ChainStore chainStore) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.modeWork = modeWork;
        this.url = url;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.chainStore = chainStore;
    }

    public Shop(int id, String name, String address, String modeWork, String url, Double latitude, Double longitude) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.modeWork = modeWork;
        this.url = url;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public ChainStore getChainStore() {
        return chainStore;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getModeWork() {
        return modeWork;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
}
```

Имеется класс, который хранит список экземпляров предыдущего класса:

```
public class Shops {
    private ArrayList<Shop> shops;

    public Shops() {
    }

    public ArrayList<Shop> getShops() {
        return shops;
    }
}
```

Имеется фрагмент, где мы получаем ответ от сервера и передаем в адаптер

```
public class SearchShopsFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener{
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewShops;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;        
    public ArrayList<Shop> shops;       

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);   

        recyclerViewShops = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewShops);
        recyclerViewShops.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewShops.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));   

            loadData(null, locality_id);          
    }    
    public void loadData(String query, int locality_id){
        adapter=null;
        recyclerViewShops.setAdapter(adapter);
        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);    
        Call<Shops> call = service.getShops(query, locality_id);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Shops>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Shops> call, Response<Shops> response) {
                 //Получили магазины и передали в адаптер
                shops = response.body().getShops();    
                adapter = new ShopsAdapter(shops, getActivity());
                Log.e("responce",String.valueOf(response.body().getShops()));
                progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
                recyclerViewShops.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Shops> call, Throwable t) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
                Log.e("error",t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Адаптер:

```
public class ShopsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShopsAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private List<Shop> shops;
    private Context ctx;

    public ShopsAdapter(List<Shop> shops, Context ctx) {
        this.shops = shops;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_shops, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ShopsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Shop shop = shops.get(position);
        Log.e("error",shop.chainStore.type);
        holder.tvShopName.setText(shop.name);
        holder.tvChainStores.setText(shop.chainStore.name);
        holder.tvShopAddress.setText(shop.address);
        holder.tvShopModeWork.setText(shop.modeWork);
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return shops.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView tvShopName;
        public TextView tvChainStores;
        public TextView tvShopAddress;
        public TextView tvShopModeWork;
        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvShopName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShopName);
            tvChainStores = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChainStores);
            tvShopAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShopAddress);
            tvShopModeWork = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShopModeWork);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //что-то делаем при нажатии на элемент recyclerview
                }
            });
        }
    }  
}
```

API:

```
@GET("shops")
    Call<Shops> getShops(@Query("query") String query,@Query("locality_id") int locality_id);
```

Думаю мой код поможет вам. Возможно где-то можно сделать по-другому, но я сам недавно знакомился с retrofit, поэтому я не эксперт)

Comment: я тоже не эксперт, я только недавно сам ковырялся и всех спрашивал казалось-бы простые вещи))

Comment: И да добавьте if(responce.isSuccerssful) в onResponse, в моем коде его нет

Comment: ок, теперь самое главное понять как ваш ответ адаптировать для моих нужд)) в любом случае спасибо

Comment: я вроде практически довел свои классы и апи до нужного состояния, но у меня все-равно остались сомнения по поводу соответствия моих классов ответу с сервера, для уточнения некоторых деталей создать новый вопрос или этот обновить?

Comment: Да можете внизу своего вопроса добавить с пометкой update, я обычно так делаю

Comment: ок, сейчас попробую, а то вроде все сделал почти так как и у вас, но приложение слетает

Comment: Кидайте Код ошибок в вопрос